# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Backend\Controller' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Buenas estoy teniendo un problema con un controlador, y nose porque no lo encuentra.

web.php:

Esta es mi ruta que lleva al metodo add de mi controlador ContactController.

```
Route::get('/add', 'Backend\ContactController@add')->name('contacts.add');
```

Mi modelo por otro lado se encuentra vacío:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contact extends Model
{
    //
}
```

y por ultimo mi controlador ContactController:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Model\Contact;
    
    class ContactController extends Controller
    {
        //
        public function view(){ 
            $allData = Customer::all();
            return view('backend.contact.view-contact', compact('allData'));
        }
    
        public function add(){ 
            
            return view('backend.contact.add-contact');
        }
    
        public function store(Request $request){
            $contact = new Customer();
            $contact->name = $request->name;
            $customer->lastname = $request->lastname;
            $customer->position = $request->position;
            $customer->mobile_no = $request->mobile_no;
            $customer->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
            $customer->save();
            Session::flash('success');
            return redirect()->route('customers.view');
        }
    }
```

Dentro de controllers tengo un directorio llamado Backend donde esta los controladores que no son del Auth.

Y esta es mi vista sidebar.blade.php:

```
<li class="nav-item has-treeview">
                <a href="{{ route('contacts.add') }}" class="nav-link text-white">
                    <i class="far fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <p class="ml-2">
                        Contactos
                    </p>
                </a>
            </li>
```

Donde llamo a la ruta con el método add de contacts. Alguien puede llegar a ver si no estoy incluyendo el controlador de manera correcta o directamente no lo incluí o cualquier tipo de error que me este causando esto?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ tendria que agregar eso en donde exactamente? en ContactController? Y en cuanto a dar mas detalles del error, literalmente el error esta como lo puse no hay una palabra mas ni menos en el mensaje de error.

Answer (score 3):

Cuando haces referencia a una clase, como en `... extends Controller` cuando defines tu clase ContactController, PHP busca esa clase en su espacio de nombres actual.

En este caso, el espacio de nombre actual es el que declaraste en la primer línea:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;
```

Sin embargo, la clase `Controller` no existe en el espacio de nombres `App\Http\Controllers\Backend`, sino en `App\Http\Controllers`, y por eso, PHP no encuentra la clase `Controller` de la que extiendes tu `ContactController`.

Dicho eso, tienes un par de opciones para resolverlo:

1. [Importarla con el operador `use`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing)

```php
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;
    
    //...
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    
    class ContactController extends Controller
    {
        //...
```

2. [Utilizar el nombre completamente cualificado de la clase](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.basics.php):

```php
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;
    
    //...
    
    class ContactController extends \App\Http\Controllers\Controller
    {
        //...
```